# Get and set index of jssor in javascript programatically

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, jssor, selectedindex

i have [jssor](http://www.jssor.com/development/index.html) slider which is working perfectly but now i dont know how to set 
index in javascript can you please help. I know hot set index in options. Actually i have to set index at document ready by getting url/id here is my   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/g3xxnLbj/) or any other suggestions

```
jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
        $AutoPlaySteps: 4,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
        $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
        $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
        $StartIndex: 0,                                  //[Optional]  Index of slide to display when initialize, default value is 0
        $Loop: 0,                                           //[Optional]Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
        $SlideDuration: 160,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
        $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
        $SlideWidth: 200,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
        //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
        $SlideSpacing: 3,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
        $DisplayPieces: 4,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
        $ParkingPosition: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
        $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
        $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
        $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

        $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 0,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
            $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
            $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
            $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
            $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
            $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
        },

        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
            $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
            $Steps: 4                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        }
    };

    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("container", options);


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//detect url to check index to show at the begninning.

```
var indexToShowAtTheBeginning = 1;
var options = {
    ...
    $StartIndex: indexToShowAtTheBeginning,
    ...
};
```

Also, you can change index at runtime in following manner,

```
jssor_slider1.$GoTo(index);
```

or

```
jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(index);
```

Comment: how to do you get the index whose class is active

Comment: jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex()